# How to calculate KL Divergence between two batches of distributions in Pytroch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

Given a batch of distributions, which represented as a pytorch tensor:

```
A = torch.tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 5., 1., 2.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 4., 2., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 5., 1., 1.],
        [0., 1., 1., 0., 2., 3., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 2., 1., 3., 1., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 2., 0., 5., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 2., 1., 4., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 2., 4., 1., 0., 1., 0.]], device='cuda:0')
```

`A` is a batch of distributions, which consists of eight distributions.
Now, given another batch of distributions `B`:

```
B = torch.tensor([[0., 0., 1., 4., 2., 1., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 5., 1., 2., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 4., 2., 3., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 7., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 2., 4., 0., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1., 3., 1., 3., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 4., 1., 0., 2., 0.],
        [1., 0., 1., 5., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 5., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 3., 2., 2., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 2., 4., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
        [1., 0., 4., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.]], device='cuda:0')
```

`B` has 12 distributions. I want to calculate the KL Divergence between each distribution in `A` and each distribution in `B`, and then obtain a KL Distance Matrix, of which shape is `12*8`. I know to use loop structure and `torch.nn.functional.kl_div()` to reach it. Is there any other methods in pytorch to implement it **without** using for-loop?

Here is my implementation using for-loop:

```
p_1 = F.softmax(A, dim = -1)
p_2 = F.softmax(B, dim = -1)
C = torch.empty(size = (A.shape[0], B.shape[0]), dtype = torch.float)

for i,a in enumerate(p_1):
    for j,b in enumerate(p_2):
        C[i][j] =  torch.nn.functional.kl_div(a.log(), b)
print(C)
```

Output is :

```
tensor([[0.4704, 0.5431, 0.3422, 0.6284, 0.3985, 0.2003, 0.4925, 0.5739, 0.5793,
         0.3992, 0.5007, 0.4934],
        [0.3416, 0.4518, 0.2950, 0.5263, 0.0218, 0.2254, 0.3786, 0.4747, 0.3626,
         0.1823, 0.2960, 0.2937],
        [0.3845, 0.4306, 0.2722, 0.5022, 0.4769, 0.1500, 0.3964, 0.4556, 0.4609,
         0.3396, 0.4076, 0.3933],
        [0.2862, 0.3752, 0.2116, 0.4520, 0.1307, 0.1116, 0.3102, 0.3990, 0.2869,
         0.1464, 0.2164, 0.2225],
        [0.1829, 0.2674, 0.1763, 0.3227, 0.0244, 0.1481, 0.2067, 0.2809, 0.1675,
         0.0482, 0.1271, 0.1210],
        [0.4359, 0.5615, 0.4427, 0.6268, 0.0325, 0.4160, 0.4749, 0.5774, 0.3492,
         0.2093, 0.3015, 0.3014],
        [0.0235, 0.0184, 0.0772, 0.0286, 0.3462, 0.1461, 0.0142, 0.0162, 0.3524,
         0.1824, 0.2844, 0.2988],
        [0.0097, 0.0171, 0.0680, 0.0284, 0.2517, 0.1374, 0.0082, 0.0148, 0.2403,
         0.1058, 0.2100, 0.1978]], device='cuda:0')
```

Comment: are the values in `A` and `B` are "frequencies" or "log probabilities"? you have zeros in the probabilities, I suppose this can be an issue for KL. Can you provide the desired output that you currently compute with loops?

Comment: @Shai thanks for your reminding, I have modified the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [`nn.KLDivLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.7.1/generated/torch.nn.KLDivLoss.html#torch.nn.KLDivLoss), the formula for computing the KL divergence is

```py
kl = torch.mean(b * (torch.log(b) - a))
```

We can use [broadcasting](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html) to compute the KL efficiently:

```py
# avoid NaNs from log(0)
lB = B.clone()
lB[B==0] = 1.

# do the computation efficiently
C = (B[None, ...] * (torch.log(lB[None, ...]) - A[:, None, :])).mean(dim=-1)
```

Coming to think of it, I'm not sure what you are asking makes much sense. Your `A` and `B` tensors are filled with numbers, but they do not represent distributions (they do not sum to 1). Please consider carefully what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my question,  ```[1,1,2,2,3,5]``` in ```A``` means 1 appears twice, 2 appears twice, 3 appears once and 5 appears once. For example, ```A``` contains three graphs (each row represents a graph), and there are 6 nodes in each graph. ```[1,1,2,2,3,5]``` means the degree of each node in the first graph in ```A```. So I  treat it as the a distribution, and I want to calculate the KL divergence between each degree distribution in ```A``` and each distribution in ```B```. Maybe I need to transform them to probability distributions first.

Comment: @MarioKZZ the way pytorch interpret `A` and `B` is not at all the way you describe. the numbers you get are, therefore, meaningless.